# Password does not work after sleep

Tags: macos, active-directory, lockscreen

I’m going to try to be as thorough as I can, but if you have questions or would like additional tests. I will provide more detail as I can. I have a small number of computers exhibiting intermittent issues when waking from sleep.

Some details:
Bound to Active Directory (although the bind is likely broken when the issue occurs)
OSX - 10.12.3
Machine is Encrypted

Symptoms:
When a user sleeps their machine which enables a locked screen saver, and then attempts to wake the machine, they are unable to log in using their credentials.

If they click on "Switch User" they are then able to log into their account, however, they are not recognized as an admin and can not run sudo commands or unlock system preferences.

It seems, at least with the computer I was able to get hands on with, that they can not authenticate in terminal or system prefs UNLESS they change their network connection to reflect the connection that allowed them to log in. So if they switch user, then connect to wifi, they can not authenticate in sysprefs, but if they turn off wifi, then they are able to authenticate.

When clicking "Switch User" the wi-fi appears to drop, and thus, lets them log in.

Restarting resolves the issue for some users but not others (unverified, going off user input, the machine I restarted did resolve the issue, at least temporarily.)

Generally when I see this issue, the computer seems to have become unbound from Active Directory. Re-binding it appears to resolve the issue temporarily (until AD drops the keychain item again).

The issue was present prior to upgrading to OSX 10.12.

It seems to me like the computer knows to check with AD if the internet is available, but if AD is unreachable or the credentials are not accepted, then it does not know to default to the local cache, unless the internet is turned off completely. I'm not sure what file or files may be involved in that, but I would like to change that file to default to the local cache when internet is connected but AD is unreachable as well as when no internet is present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the opendirectoryd daemon which bugs when trying to bind with AD.
The raw solution is basically to kill the daemon which will restart and rebind somehow.

There are many ways to automate the kill, a cronjob would work but will require to have the killall command run every minute, which is very dirty.

I am using sleepwatcher (available with homebrew) and set it to launch the kill command everytime the laptop is going out of sleep, which works like a charm.

It's a workaround, but seems Apple doesn't really work on a fix for that issue which is ongoing for years.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I wish there was a better solution, but I will check out sleepwatcher. I'll leave this unanswered for a bit to see if anyone has other ideas.